# Can't create file __init__py, Permission Denied

Tags: files, permissions, python

So I'm trying to setup a python project and for whatever reason i can't create a file called `__init__.py`...

I've tried doing all the following:

```
vim __init__.py               // opens file but can't save
sudo vim __init__.py          // same as command above
echo "" > __init__.py         // outputs: bash: __init__.py: Permission denied
sudo echo "" > __init__.py    // same output as above
```

The directory I'm trying to make these calls in is empty so there are no other conflicting files...

Does anyone know what the issue here may be?

---

Update:

`ls -ld` returns `drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 27 09:47 .`

`id` returns `uid=1000(quinn) gid=1000(quinn) groups=1000(quinn),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),119(lpadmin),130(lxd),131(sambashare)`

Comment: Please note the 4th try doesn't do what you think it does:  you run `echo ""` with elevated privilege (don't do this just to get around permission problems!!!) but the redirection is evaluated outside that, as for any `cmd > file` sequence. This takes a while to get used to if you're not used to Linux shells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that you're unable to create the file in the current directory is that your user (`quinn`, which the `id` utility reports) has no write permission in the directory (which is owned by `root`, which is evident in the `ls` output).

It's not clear whether the directory *should* be owned by the root user, or *why* it is owned by the root user, but this is the reason you can't create the file as the user `quinn`.